# ImportError: cannot import name 'main' after installing python3.6 and pipenv

Tags: python, python3, pip

After installing python3.6 and pipenv I tried to install `requests` with the command `pip3 install requests` and getting this error-

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`
```

Here is how I installed python3.6

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl libreadline-dev

$ cd ~

$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz

$ tar zxf Python-3.6.1.tgz

$ cd Python-3.6.1

$ ./configure

$ make

$ sudo make install
```

And here is how I installed pip env-
`pip3 install pipenv`

After that i started getting that error.
I have tried uninstalling python, python3, python-pip, python3-pip using below commands

```
$ sudo apt purge python

$ sudo apt purge python3

$ sudo apt purge python-pip

$ sudo apt purge python3-pip
```

Then installed them again using below commands
`$ sudo apt install python`

```
$ sudo apt install python3

$ sudo apt install python-pip

$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

But still getting that error. Also I always used `sudo apt-get update` before using those commands. 
After installing python3 again. When i check the version using the command `python3 -V` it shows `python 3.6`
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

First, check the location of the file:

```
$ which pip
path -> /usr/bin/pip
```

Then, open terminal and enter:

```
$ cd /usr/bin/    --> (path of pip)
$ sudo nano pip
```

In the file, you will see:

```
import sys
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.exit(main())
```

You must change to:

```
import sys
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

Save the changes and exit

Comment: This after hours and hours of trying finally solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: This was the answer to my problem too, none of the weird `hash` commands and stuff like the other threads suggest...

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks a lot  @Bangladesh 71